# how to get the attribute value defined in html file of template url in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

below is my directive,

```
app.directive('search', function($rootScope, $timeout, dynamicValues) {
    return {
        scope: {
            myname: '=',
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/template.html',
    };
}));
```

and below is my template.html

```
<input type="text" name="Name" myname = "maho">
```

so my requirement is I need to get the value of myname attribute i.e "maho" in my directive I tried it using Attr as below

```
scope.variable = iAttrs.myname;
alert("myname value is..." + scope.variable);
```

but I am getting undefined value please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.directive('search', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
          scope.variable = attrs.myname;
        }

    };
});
```

Isolate scopes are for passing variables from parent directives. ngModel binds an element's value to a scope variable.

[egghead.io video regarding isolate scopes](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope)

[docs for ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iS8WPBXzLbRRXtn7XLIz?p=preview)

Comment: getting value in this way but I want to give this <input type="text" myname="maho">'in template.html only not in this template.

Comment: @user3824049 then put that in your template.html and use `templateUrl`

Comment: @user3824049 Updated plunker to use `templateUrl`. Hope it helps.

Comment: followed your code it helped me but I am getting below error at scope.variable = attrs.myname;                                TypeError: Cannot read property 'myname' of undefined

Comment: @user3824049 then the problem is your code, can't help if you don't post it.

Answer (score 1):

did you check attrs.myname value first?

```
app.directive('search', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      myname: '='
    },
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<input type="text" name="Name" myname="maho">',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(attrs.myname);

      scope.variable = attrs.myname;
      console.log(scope.variable);
    }
  };
});
```

on some page,

```
<search></search>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: at this console.log(attrs.myname); line getting error as  Cannot read property 'myname' of undefined

Comment: I think your template didn't apply properly. please see the updated answer.